# ThreadSanitizer only prints 2 frames

Tags: c++, gcc, thread-sanitizer

For some reason, the callstacks produced by ThreadSanitizer in my log are always exactly two frames (#0, #1). Is there a hidden setting that limits the number of frames?

Regards

Comment: When *I* use it I get all stack frames in error dumps. There's no hidden "two frames only" setting. Could you please provide a [mcve] as well as info on what compiler you are using and what exact commandline options you are passing to the compiler, so that we can try to reproduce.?

Comment: I have never used this, but I found the documentation. It has an option called "history size" that defaults to two. Maybe this is what you're looking for. https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/ThreadSanitizerFlags

Comment: I'm curious to know if that solved your problem...

Answer (score 0):

To make it short, there was a library in the stack that was not instrumented just starting with frame #2. This seems to cause Tsan to omit the rest of the stack too.

The history setting did not help.

Thanks anyways.